# Generating a file during "Build", c#, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I generate a file during "Build" in Visual Studio using C#?

I want to create a `.txt` File and add some text in it. The file should be created directly when I press Build and save it in a place where the Release or Debug Folder is.

Comment: If the file is *hard-coded*, you can simply add it to the project and within the properties enable `Copy if newer`. If the file content should be generated by some code at build time you either check *Text templates (T4)* or do something within the pre-build event.

Comment: @Oliver: nice catch, I'll add your comment to my answer for completeness.

Comment: @Oliver Thank you... its actualy hardcoded yes. It should be a setting.txt File... My problem is... if the user deletes the file by mistake .. should create it whenever the programm is starting. But I already covered this.... but I think adding the hardcoded File inside Project is the easiest way :D I was just thinking way too difficult ^^

Comment: @Stefan but ! I will need it ! :D

Answer (score 6):

You should have a look at [build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022).

Typically you can run any kind of script pre and post build - including the (re)generation of a text file.

To copy files into the output path, you can use the `OutputPath` variable. See the MACRO section and [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022) on how to use them.

As by @Oliver's comment: if it is a static file, you can just include it in the project using its properties and select: `Copy if newer`.

Taken from the documentation:

[image]

And a subset of the MACROs

[image]

Comment: Oh nice ! Thank you :) I will mark this as answer in 3 minutes :D Thank you again !

Comment: Again thank you ! I think I will need this later ... As for now I will just add the File manualy because its hardcoded :D Thank you :)